# How to translate errors and attributes of model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've changed default locale of my project, and now there is the following error:

```
Average check translation missing: ru.activemodel.errors.models.place_restaurant.attributes.average_check.blank
```

Average check is ':average_check' in 'PlaceRestaurant' model. I want to change 'Average check' text for russian analogue, and add text of error. I've made 'ru.yml' file:

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      place_restaurant: "Some russian analogue"
    attributes:
      place_restaurant:
        average_check: "Some russian analogue"
```

But it doesn't work, average_check is still 'Average check'. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error message gives you all structure how it should looks like. Yaml should be:

```
ru:
 activemodel:
   errors:
     models:
       place_restaurant:
         attributes:
           average_check:
             blank: "Не может быть пустым"
```

In general this error message seems to be strange for me. Are you using default presence validation?

Answer (score 0):

This is how a Locale file should e like. Yo have not mentioned the "errors".

https://gist.github.com/satyatechsavy/7671560

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that this question is already answered. Sorry!